# How to add Objects in table rows and columns using Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hi i have a table described below. I have a object with rows and columns which i am saving in  data base.

I want to show that object in the table rows and columns according to data.

For example my object is `chart[rows][columns]`

so if it is `chart[0][0]` it will show in first row and first column
so if it is `chart[0][1]` it will show in first row and Second Column and so on...
Also in my case the row will always be 0 and i have fixed three columns show below

how i can get this functionality using Jquery

My Table is

```
<table id="dashboardDesigner" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td id="Col1" style="border: solid 1px black; height: 100px; width: 300px" class="connectedSortable">
        </td>
        <td id="Col2" style="border: solid 1px black; height: 100px; width: 300px" class="connectedSortable">
        </td>
        <td id="Col3" style="border: solid 1px black; height: 100px; width: 300px" class="connectedSortable">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has contains function that can look for certain string (http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/). So all you have to do is get some input to send the variable data into selector like this:

```
$("td:contains('" + variable + "')");
```

and then select it's parent:

```
$("td:contains('" + variable + "')").parent();
```

and display it:

```
$("td:contains('" + variable + "')").parent().html().appendTo("div.showFindResult");
```